# Register oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm new to Java web service. I've been playing with it for a few days and finally I am able to connect to the Oracle database on a different machine. Happy so far.

The samples that I have seen on the web so far saying that you only need to register the oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver once.

How do you do that on a web service? Right now I register it every time the function e.g. getUserFullName is called.

Any input is appreciated.

Edited:
here's one of the functions:

```
public static String getUserName(int id) throws SQLException {
    String returnValue = "";
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rset = null;
    Connection conn = null; 

    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myOracleIP:1521/myOracleDB", "admin", "password");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rset = stmt.executeQuery("select name from tbl_users where id = " + id);

        while(rset.next()) {
            returnValue = rset.getString("name");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        returnValue = "jdbc.getUserName -- Exception: " + ex.getMessage();
    }
    finally {
        // close resultset
        if(rset != null)
            if(!rset.isClosed())
                rset.close();
        // close statement
        if(stmt != null)
            if(!stmt.isClosed())
                stmt.close();
        // close connection
        if(conn != null)
            if(!conn.isClosed())
                conn.close();
    }

    stmt = null;
    rset = null;
    conn = null;

    return returnValue;
}
```

JNDI Function

```
public static String getNameWithJNDI(int id) throws SQLException {
    int statusCode = 0;
    String returnValue = "Open DB";
    DataSource dc = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rset = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Context context = null;

    try {
        context = new InitialContext();
        // my datasource from the GlassFish 
        dc = (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/myConnection");
        context.close();
    }
    catch(NamingException e) {
        statusCode = 1;
        returnValue = "jdbc.GetNameWithJNDI - InitialContext Error: " + e.getMessage();
    }

    if((statusCode == 0) && (dc != null)) {
        try {
            conn = dc.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            rset = stmt.executeQuery("select name from tbl_users where id = " + id);

            if(rset != null) {
                while(rset.next()) {
                    returnValue = "JNDI: " + rset.getString("name");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            statusCode = 1;
            returnValue = "jdbc.GetNameWithJNDI - Database Error: " + e.getMessage();  
        }
        finally {
            // close resultset
            if(rset != null)
                if(!rset.isClosed())
                    rset.close();
            // close statement
            if(stmt != null)
                if(!stmt.isClosed())
                    stmt.close();
            // close connection
            if(conn != null)
                if(!conn.isClosed())
                    conn.close();
        }
    }



    dc = null;
    stmt = null;
    rset = null;
    conn = null;
    context = null;

    return returnValue;     
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you registering it?? what type of function? class

Comment: Code please, also little elaboration on web service part of your question

Answer (score 1):

JDBC 4 compliant drivers don't need to be registered. If you are using an application server, the usual way is to create a `DataSource` in your application server and use that from within your application (by referencing it using JNDI) instead of creating connections using `DriverManager`. The application server `DataSource` usually also takes care of things like connection pooling.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will look into your suggestion as well.

Comment: Mark, thank you for the advice. I created the datasource in Glassfish vm and created a new function in the webservice to utilize the datasource and it works. I added the new function above.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a JNDI lookup for each time a JDBC resource needs to be used, especially if you are using a Java Application Server, which it seems you are (as you are conducting Web Services). This means that you don't have to keep loading the JDBC Driver each time. For example, you may want to have a look at the following: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/samapp9.htm

Connection Pooling can also be found at the following article: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jndi-datasource-examples.html#pooling-datasources

Comment: I publish the .war web service onto the GlashFish4 Open Source vm on my development PC; and the Oracle DB is in a different PC. Everything is new in this java world. Thank you.

Comment: How I do know if I am running an application server or not if I am using the GlassFish4 Open Source VM?

Comment: blackpanther: thanks for the URLs. great example on how to use the connection pool. i definitely use it.